# retrofit data using query parameters in android

Tags: java, android

this is my url  every time token value changes when user login how to get json data

from following json using retrofit android

http://192.168.1.111/Innovative/onetip/admin/pages/api_login.php?cid=321&token=3176

token id changes everytime when login succesfull how to get data

```json
{
  "0": "321",
  "1": "Aaryaman",
  "2": "Jayshankar singh",
  "3": "aaryamans@gmail.com",
  "4": "aarya",
  "5": "$2y$12$2vieUktY.BbErcwPE8Vae.scmjR0OZbJcw9XctBigfT5AD9fE9Uwq",
  "6": "9424705205",
  "7": "22",
  "8": "4ek3to31qtyp8ac73y5q",
  "9": "1562321930",
  "10": "ddd3333",
  "11": "12",
  "12": null,
  "13": null,
  "14": "0",
  "15": "1250",
  "16": "1019443533",
  "17": "3176",
  "id": "321",
  "name": "Aaryaman",
  "father_name": "Jayshankar singh",
  "email": "aaryamans@gmail.com",
  "username": "aarya",
  "pass": "$2y$12$2vieUktY.BbErcwPE8Vae.scmjR0OZbJcw9XctBigfT5AD9fE9Uwq",
  "mobile": "9424705205",
  "payment": "22",
  "transaction_id": "4ek3to31qtyp8ac73y5q",
  "reg_date": "1562321930",
  "pan": "ddd3333",
  "rsrch_cat": "12",
  "payment_mode": null,
  "receipt": null,
  "isDeleted": "0",
  "risk_score": "1250",
  "tele_id": "1019443533",
  "session_token": "3176"
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be more precise, what is your code to call this endpoint ? Are you asking how to parse the response or how to make your token Id dynamic ?

Comment: provide some code and be more clear and precise about the problem, no one can help you this way, use ``` [code] ``` blocks for your code

Comment: how to parse retrofit response using random token id in android